# Can't log into application after domain controller upgrade to Windows Server 2008. Active Directory issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory, windows-server-2008, directoryservices

I am having an issue with a web application I mainatin built with .net framwework version 4. Everything was working fine until we upgraded the Active Directoy domain controller to Windows Server 2008. Whenever a new user is added to Active Directory and put into a group they should be able to use the application but now everytime we add a new user they can not log in. Also, users that were added before the upgrade have no issues logging in.

I have tried things such as editing the web.config file (connection string) and debugging the code but I have come up with nothing. While stepping through the c# code I noticed that the program is unable to pick up the roles of the new users but is able to pick up the roles of current users.
I also suspect it may have something to do with the System.DirectoryServices dll not being compatible with the new server even though it is version 4.0.

So I am wondering if anyone has encountered the same issue with upgrading a domain controller to Windows Server 2008 with Active Directory installed and if so how did you fix the issue?

Thanks for any feedback.

Comment: Did you raise the Active Directory functional level?  This is not a suggestion, but a question to provide some information for readers to consider.

Comment: It has not been raised. I am unable to because the old 2003 server  is still active as well. Do you think that may be the issue?

Comment: Did you run adprep before installing the 2008 DC?  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733027(WS.10).aspx

Comment: In general, you can run a Windows 2008 DC in a Windows 2003 functional-level domain.  However, that isn't to say there isn't a bug in Windows or in the .NET Framework that is causing the problem you are seeing.  I would not be surprised if something like this occurred if adprep wasn't run, so if it wasn't that would be the first thing I would do if I were you.  Get good backups first.